# How should I extracted this url get string

Tags: c++, regex, qt4, cgi

How should I extract a URL for example "action=add&var1=5&var2=6" into

```
QString action; 
QVector<QStringList> vars;
```

efficiently?
I am using apache, c++ cgi and the QT libary. Ask for more detail if needed.

Comment: Are you okay with adding an external library as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [QUrl](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qurl.html#addQueryItem) class that comes with Qt. Set it to the url and then use `allEncodedQueryItemValues` to get the pairs.